# I am new to python loops and I am trying to create a loop iteration where I start with 11 and find the first 42 terms

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
start = 11
second = 8
third = 14
list = [start, second, third]
for number in range(42):
    start = start + second + third 
    print(f'{number+1}. {start}')

#using a for or while loop, I want to calculate the first 42 terms. Each term is calculated by adding the 3 previous terms
```

> Output should look like
>
> 1. 11
> 2. 8
> 3. 14
> 4. 33
> 5. 55
>    etc...
>
> enter code here

Comment: Please update your post with what you've tried, and let us know where you're stuck. :)

Comment: I am stuck on where I create the while loop and add the three variables. I get 33 but it is just repeating forever without increasing.

Comment: Let's start with `i` first. The variable `i`  isn't getting updated, so you are in an infinite loop. `i` will always be 0, and will never be 43 because there is no statement to update it in your loop. Does that make sense?

Comment: I rewrote the code to a for loop since I ended up finding it much easier. Now the thing I am having trouble with is updating the part where the previous 3 numbers are added to get the new number. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a way to keep track of your values, something like a list/array.

Comment: after I use a list, what next?

Comment: Let's think about it what needs to happen from after 3, since that is when you start using the last 3 terms. Starting from 4, you need to get the total/sum of 11, 8, 14, and add it to your list, so that it will contain `[11, 8, 14, 33]`, and when you get to the 5th loop, you can get the sum of `[8, 14, 33]`, and add it to the list. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close and I saw that you took the effort updated your code a few times. Let me walk you through a beginner setup, and you can fill in the last bit:

```
start = 11
second = 8
third = 14

my_list = [start, second, third]

# Loop
for i in range(42):
    print(i, my_list[i])
    # I only need to start doing something after the 3rd item, 2 because we count from 0
    if i >= 2:
        beginning_index = i - 2
        ending_index = i + 1

        # get my most recent three
        last_three = my_list[beginning_index:ending_index]
        # You can also do something called backward slicing instead of 
        # giving a range of items in a list to retrieve
        # This means give me the most recent 3 items
        # last_three = my_list[-3:]      

        # sum those three
        last_three = sum(last_three)

        # add the sum of last three to my list
        my_list.append(last_three)
```

Comment: so last_three = sum(my_list) ?

Comment: Close. Think about the two variables `beginning_index` and `ending_index` and their relationship with `my_list`. Once `i >= 2`, `beginning_index` will be 0, and `ending_index` will be 3, then when `i == 3`, it will be 1 and 4. Look at the slicing stackoverflow and see if you can think about what I'm hinting.

Comment: so I use slice instead of sum?

Comment: how do i implement it?

Comment: You use both. Try only coping everything before the `# Loop` and do `print(my_list[0:1])`, `print(my_list[1:2])` and `print(my_list[0:2])`. Then do `print(sum(my_list[0:2]))`. Think about what's happening

Comment: I don't know man. This seems to be outside what I am supposed to do. Is there a more simpler way? Like Creating three variables to store these terms and update them with each loop iteration?

Comment: Yep, you can absolutely also do it that way, mine is just visually easier to understand.

Comment: Could you show me how to do it that way?

Comment: Maybe, let me ask you, what is it that you didn't understand about the list and slicing notation?

Comment: I did not understand the basics and how to properly input it when it comes to putting it in a list. Sorry if its such an inconvenience. I have been trying to do this for 3 hours now.

Comment: I updated the code to give the answer, you were close with your first comment. If you want to know how to do it with just updating variables, please make a new post with that requirement. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! and My bad I am new to this so sorry for any inconvenience.